# Getting KeyError when implementing Turtle trading strategy with python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to implement the turtle trading strategy in Python, but I am getting a KeyError when I try to run the code. I have imported the necessary libraries and have the data in a DataFrame. I have also calculated the 20-day and 10-day moving averages and the average true range (ATR).

When I try to iterate through the rows of the data and set the position (long or short) and profit/loss, I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzTZf.png)

```
import yfinance as yf

# Set the start and end dates
start_date = '2022-01-01'
end_date = '2022-12-31'

# Get the data for ETH-USD
# data = yf.Ticker("ETH-USD").history(start=start_date, end=end_date, period="1d", interval="1d")
# print(data)

# Save the data to a CSV file
# data.to_csv('eth-usd.csv')


import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv('eth-usd.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

# Calculate the 20-day and 10-day moving averages
data['20d'] = data['Close'].rolling(20).mean().dropna()
data['10d'] = data['Close'].rolling(10).mean().dropna()

# Calculate the average true range (ATR)
data['ATR'] = data['High'].dropna() - data['Low'].dropna()
data['ATR'] = data['ATR'].dropna().rolling(10).mean()

# Set the initial capital
initial_capital = 10000

# Set the number of shares to trade
shares_to_trade = 100

# Create a column to store the position (long or short)
data['Position'] = None

# Create a column to store the profit/loss
data['P/L'] = 0

# Create a column to store the returns
data['Returns'] = 0

# Iterate through the rows of the data
for i in range(1, len(data)):

    # If the 20-day moving average is above the 10-day moving average, go long
    if data.loc[i, '20d'] > data.loc[i, '10d']:
        data.loc[i, 'Position'] = 'Long'
        data.loc[i, 'P/L'] = -shares_to_trade * data.loc[i, 'Close']

    # If the 10-day moving average is above the 20-day moving average, go short
    elif data.loc[i, '10d'] > data.loc[i, '20d']:
        data.loc[i, 'Position'] = 'Short'
        data.loc[i, 'P/L'] = shares_to_trade * data.loc[i, 'Close']

# Calculate the returns
data['Returns'] = data['P/L'].cumsum().div(initial_capital)

# Plot the returns
data['Returns'].plot()
```

I was expecting to get the result but an error popped up. And I can not really debug it since I'm lacking enough experience.

Answer (score 1):

It was indexed by year and not by numbers adding this code `data = data.reset_index()` before the # Iterate through the rows of the data solved the problem.